# transpose/pivot csv text file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I need to transpose/pivot a CSV file. Don't know if that is possible

Suppose this CSV file content:

```
filename;rating;id;summary
S4348gjO.doc;good;0001;describing how to reach your goals
S4348gjO.doc;good;0002;some recipes for avoiding an argument
S4348gjO.doc;bad;0003;boring part of the page
A234HK.doc;fairly good;0001;how to deploy a server
A234HK.doc;bad;0002;start and stop the server
```

Output must be:

```
filename;good;fairly good;bad;id
S4348gjO.doc;describing how to reach your goals; ; ;0001
S4348gjO.doc;some recipes for avoiding an argument; ; ;0002
S4348gjO.doc; ; ;boring part of the page;0003
A234HK.doc; ;how to deploy a server; ;0001
A234HK.doc; ; ;start and stop the server;0002
```

Comment: I don't understand how the input became the output.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
FNR==1{print "filename;good;fairly good;bad;id"}
$2=="good"{print $1, $4, " ", " ", $3}
$2=="fairly good"{print $1, " ", $4, " ", $3}
$2=="bad"{print $1, " ", " ", $4, $3}' infile
```

so the corresponding rating column contains the summary and the other two will get just a space (per your example - if you need an empty field replace `" "` with `""`)

Answer (score 1):

A little modification the [don_crissti's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304593/89144)

```
awk -F\; '
    BEGIN{
        P["good"]="%s;%s;;;%s\n"
        P["fairly good"]="%s;;%s;;%s\n"
        P["bad"]="%s;;;%s;%s\n"
        }                         
    FNR==1{
        print "filename;good;fairly good;bad;id"
        next
        }
    {
        printf(P[$2],$1,$4,$3)
        }
    ' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `reshape` sub-command of Miller (`mlr`) to pivot the data using the `rating` field as the key field and the `summary` field as the value field.  Then assigning empty values to the new fields that are missing from each record, and reordering the fields in the order shown in the question:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s rating,summary then unsparsify then reorder -f filename,good,'fairly good',bad,id file
filename;good;fairly good;bad;id
S4348gjO.doc;describing how to reach your goals;;;0001
S4348gjO.doc;some recipes for avoiding an argument;;;0002
S4348gjO.doc;;;boring part of the page;0003
A234HK.doc;;how to deploy a server;;0001
A234HK.doc;;;start and stop the server;0002
```

Filling the missing values with spaces, as in the question:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s rating,summary then unsparsify --fill-with ' ' then reorder -f filename,good,'fairly good',bad,id file
filename;good;fairly good;bad;id
S4348gjO.doc;describing how to reach your goals; ; ;0001
S4348gjO.doc;some recipes for avoiding an argument; ; ;0002
S4348gjO.doc; ; ;boring part of the page;0003
A234HK.doc; ;how to deploy a server; ;0001
A234HK.doc; ; ;start and stop the server;0002
```